# Retrofit 2 return response data object for further use

Tags: java, android, retrofit, pojo, retrofit2

I use POJO and Retrofit2 in Android to call a REST service to get some data. I do receive the data in response.body() as expected but I do not want this data to be assigned to any android UI component. I want to get this returned object and return back or work outside of the onResponse.

Sorry I am new to JAVA or callbacks but on searching found that I need to write callback but not sure how to write it. Can someone please help.

Here is the code:

```
public String getUserIPCountry(Context context){       

    ipf = new Ipinfo();

    IpinfoAPI.Factory.getInstance().getCountryCode().enqueue(new Callback<Ipinfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Ipinfo> call, Response<Ipinfo> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()){

               //Want to return/use below data outside of this method
               //response.body().getCountryCode();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Ipinfo> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the operation `getUserIPCountry` you set the `Callback` that will be called when the data arrives from the server. 
The execution doesn't stop and wait the response.
If the response from the server is OK, `onResponse` will be called and if something goes wrong, `onFailure` will be called.

So, in the `onResponse` method of the `Callback` you should notify the interested classes that the data arrives, (for example, ui classes that shows the data).

Comment: Thanks Pablo. I am only able to set data to UI elements or work inside onresponce. What I want is - I have a object public Ipinfo xyz that is created and assigned in oncreate method of type ipinfo. So part of xyz is assigned value outside of getUserIPCountry method and want to assign IP field only using xyz.setip() inside onresponse.